# Detect delete action on "input" event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to detect delete action on "input" event?
Something like inputType == "deleteContentBackward" in Chrome

Comment: delete action is what? command/key delete, backspace, cut etc.

Comment: backspace button or delete button

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript Keycodes:

- `e.keyCode === 8` for key `Backspace`
- `e.keyCode === 46` for key `Delete`

```js
document.querySelector('#input').onkeyup = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
    console.log('Deleted with key ' + e.key);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
```

Comment: thanks, but i need exactly "input" event to use
keyup fires after key is up, obviously, but i need to handle it when some text was inserted to element

Comment: You can add your code in the event handler function: `document.querySelector('#input').onkeyup`

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("my_id_name").oninput = function(e) {
     if ((e.inputType == 'deleteContentBackward') || (e.inputType == 'deleteContentForward') || (e.inputType == 'deleteByCut')){
            $('my_id_name').value = null
        })
 }
```